# Change the color based on user's current time in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a weather app where I want to implement a dynamic color (gradient) change based on a time of the day i.e. when it's morning, the background is light blue, when it's night –  it's purple, etc.

Basically, I understand there should be a global function but I don't really know how to tap into a user's actual time and write smth like:

```
switch time {

case "05:00" : 
return Color.blue

case "10:00" : 
return Color.yellow
...
...
...
}
```

Comment: The documentation has a whole section about [Dates and Times](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dates_and_times) that should be worthwhile researching for this. Besides that you should consider what is considered morning (and other parts of the day), is it really the same hardcoded value for all users and all of the year for one user?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here's how to get the current hour and minute:

```
let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
let minute = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: Date())
```

And, in your case:

```
let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())

switch hour {

case 5:
return Color.blue

case 10:
return Color.yellow
...
...
...
}
```